# Why is html>body used?

Tags: css

I came across `html>body` in one of the stylesheets and wanted to know as to why it is used.

```
html>body {
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-size: 78.75%;
}
```

Comment: It's likely because the person who wrote it doesn't fully understand CSS, and was overzealous with their specificity. There's no reason the selector couldn't just be `body`.

Comment: Unless it's a CSS hack to include or exclude a specific browser.

Comment: @Umbrella Good point. I haven't cared about IE6 in such a long time I'd forgotten that it didn't have `>` support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a [Child Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

The reason it's being used is likely because it's a hack to exclude IE6 and below. Those browsers don't understand the `>` selector.

**[More Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Child_selector_hack)**

Answer (score 2):

the '>' means that it is referencing on child elements of the parent (in this case 'html')

so for example I could have an arrangement of divs that look like so

```
<div id="outermost">
  <div class="inner">
     <div class="inner">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and i wrote some css like so

```
#outermost>.inner { background-color: #CCC; }
```

it would only apply the rules to the first level '#inner'

Obviously there is only one body tag however it used to be a hack to exclude ie6 and below to write different rules for ie7+ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Child selector, more info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

So in your code it would be any body child of html

Comment: I think marko is right about the IE hack as it sounds vaguely familiar

Answer (score 1):

'> symbol indicates `child of`
Above code means 
The style applies to all the tag body which is a child of html

```
    #sample>div
```

above applies to all divs which are children of the element with id sample